# ActivityNotFoundException при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android, activity

Логи (ACRA):

```
Failed to send crash reports for /data/data/com.mypackage.mobi/app_ACRA-approved/2017-05-11T14:23:52.623+0000.stacktrace

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=mailto:xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:957)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:939)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
    at org.acra.sender.EmailIntentSender.send(EmailIntentSender.java:55)
    at org.acra.sender.ReportDistributor.sendCrashReport(ReportDistributor.java:102)
    at org.acra.sender.ReportDistributor.distribute(ReportDistributor.java:70)
    at org.acra.sender.SenderService.onHandleIntent(SenderService.java:69)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Манифест:

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--здесь у меня ещё 2 активити-->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Валится `ActivityNotFoundException`, хотя я не создавал никаких intent-ов. Куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по логу вы где-то всё же создаете интент на отправку эмейла.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, ....);
```

А на девайсе нет приложения, которое может этот интент обработать

Comment: Intent-ов я не создавал, выходит, это acra